Question on the proper use of philosophy
Glanced at the SEP for the first time today, and noticed that most of it is focused on questions of the existence and character of deity or deities.
Admittedly, that is the subject matter that has driven European philosophy since the introduction of religions whose deities judge beliefs about them as much as, or more than, beliefs and actions about humans and our place in the world.
But it leaves me wondering whether those of us who have no axe to grind and honestly don't care about that specific debate really belong in a discussion of philosophy at all, except in understanding the history of the field and being entertained by how it evolved, or occasionally clarifying that being neither a believer or a disbeliever is a perfectly defensible stance, given the appropriate assumptions.
Or is it just that that set of topics is the one that people have felt most strongly about and spent (and spend?) the most time and effort on, and the SEP was written to support education about that history?
Having stepped in because a clarification/example of genuine agnosticism seemed to be needed, I am starting to feel that perhaps I have reached the end of my usefulness here and should step out again.
If I do remain, I may have to set up some tag filtering to keep myself from getting distracted by/involved in topics where I really have nothing insightful to add but insufficient restraint to keep my hands off the keyboard. That has been helpful in some of the other stacks.

As someone raised in the "European tradition" I'd like to point out that one of the tricks that it pulls is taking on an attitude of blandly assumed universiality - "Look, we wrote this encyclopaedia, so that must be the map of the area, indicating what is important, and where the borders are." And that just does not have to be the case, and often serves as a defense of close-mindedness. So I'm hoping you stick around and provide those alternative arguments, although I'm very sympathetic to and understanding of your frustrations, and need to distance yourself. Take care!

So it may be useful to remind folks who cite the SEP that it's defines the terminology only as used by practitioners of its traditions. SEWEP, Standard Encyclopedia of Western European Philosophy, perhaps. No, the fact that that resembles SEWER was not intentional and I apologize. Though I don't apologize for pointing that out.

I'm also having a bit of trouble grokking where we draw the line between X and philosophy-of-X, eg linguistics. Some of the recent questions feel like they are asking the wrong specialty. But every line we draw in the real world is fussy, fractal, shaded, or combination of those...

I just opened the SEP table of contents, and skimmed two random letters there, which were A and R.  A had only agnosticism, atheism, and a set of entries on Arab and Islamic philosophy that fall under the category of "about God".  R only had a set of entries under "religion".  the fraction of entries about "God" appeared from this sample to be under 10%, and that was a pretty broad definition of "about God".   Under what criteria do you think the SEP is mostly about God questions?

My quick reading may have been in error, and I grant that a better phrasing of my observation would be "about religion' rather than " about God." I'll take another look; the table of contents may have misled me.

Note I did not include the biographic entries of people like Anselm and Augustine and Ayer in my informal count -- those entries are about philosophers, not God, despite each of them having things to say about God thinking.

Hm. If they made arguments that were neither based on the assumption of God or attempting to prove that conclusion, and those are findable in the SEP without undue digging, I may need to withdraw my grumble.

I don't think the SEP is mostly about God or religion, it covers all sorts of other subjects in greater depth.  There ARE limitations to the SEP -- it mostly reflects academic Anglo-American philosophy, so its contemporary sections are primarily oriented to analytic philosophy.  Both continental philosophy and Eastern philosophy get pretty short shrift.  As a pragmatist, I also find pragmatism very underrepresented.
If you dig into the historical entries, you will find a lot of God and religion thinking.  Most early philosophers were theists, and sought to outline worldviews that meshed "naturalism" with theist thinking.  The European Rennaissance and Enlightenment philosophy has a major interest in breaking the intellectual stranglehold of Church dogma on philosophic thought, so anti-theocracy and anti-dogma arguments were a huge aspect of Western philosophic heritage, and that included a big dose of anti-theism.
Young people first encountering philosophy often reprise this historical process, and both anti-theism and theistic apologism questions often attract a lot of attention here.  As philosophy served as the means to break theocratic thought control, and was the inspiration for non-theist thinking (atheism, agnosticism, and "seeker" categories to thought were all at risk to legal execution pre-enlightenment, and all three have spread as alternatives since), it is unsurprising that these questions are hot topics for those forging their moral and ontological worldviews.
Despite the enthusiasm for religious questions on these boards, I find the dominant posting category to be questions about logic, and mathematical  and computational philosophy.  These subjects are generally unrelated to religion and God.  I think this is because of our stack exchange heritage, with coders and mathematicians sharing our boards.
The most common religion questions DO tend to be "logic" questions about religion and Gods, which I also find annoying.  Since Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, the nature of our world has increasingly been seen as a purely empirical question, not a "logical" or analytic one.  But again, with the logician and coder heritage of most SE contributors, the "logic" focus of much early thinking of people entering philosophy from that background is not surprising, and a feature of our members that should be treated with tolerance.
If you find religion questions to be dead-end uses of your time, BUT also an attractive hazard, yes developing a self-discipline filter would be wise.

Perhaps young people need not reprise the development of philosophy. How many people learn to ride a horse, sail a boat or drive a manual? I think that they should learn the basics of how computers work if they are going to program, but this idea is roundly rebuked at Computer Science Educators SE. At some point it is no longer possible to repeat history, so why bother learning it? Bigger threats are ahead.

Besides the fact that only a small fraction of contemporary philosophy, may it be western or not, revolves around religion, I would like to add another frame challenge:
Don't you think it odd that when you look into Asian pop culture like manga, anime, graphic novels, etc, there is a recurring theme that is very close to Christian (or at least Abrahamic) religion? Angels, the suffering of humanity for their sins, human finitude, the soul transcending the limits of the body - all of this happens to be part of many of the most successful series (in the adult's market branch I might add). This might have to do with the human condition including a longing for transcendence, as Plessner argued.
That being said, it cannot be stressed enough that most of these questions are posted by a small number of users and multiplied mainly through the fact that questions about God are almost a 100% candidate for Hot Network Questions because everyone has so strong opinions about them.
I cannot tell you how much I am fed up with the millionth variation of the ever same question trying to fish for popularity votes but here we are, discussing it again.

Suppose they gave a Debate and nobody came? Bake sale for an LLM? :-)

Isn't this "discussing the discussing of it", rather than "discussing it"?  (grin)

It is simply not true that God is most of the content in the SEP so your question is based on a faulty premise.

Perfectly possible I misinterpreted. I've no problem with upvoting this as helpful.

I don't know about the SEP, but there are definitely lots of places in the Internet, especially America-based Internet, that claim to be about philosophy but waste a lot of time discussing god.
It's kind of like joining up on a discussion board that says it's for foodies and discovering that it's mostly people talking about what their favorite thing to order at McDonald's is. Disappointing.

Agreed, but not an Answer to the question.

I know this is a hard ask, but we do need to ferret out the distinction between heat and light. Religion is something that people love to argue about, so there is a lot of heat that comes from that direction: lots of people wanting to make their voices heard, often in strident tones. If we filter out the heat, there are still a lot of religious thinkers producing light, but they are much more appropriately proportioned to people producing light in other branches of philosophy.
I mean, we will always have the issue that a lot of philosophical problems have crossovers with religion. Wherever philosophy wants to dig into the nature of what it means to be human, we'll find that religions have spent a few millennia trying to cover the ground, and we can't just toss out millennia's worth of thinking because it comes with baggage. Everything in philosophy comes with historical baggage. The trick is to keep our eyes on the problem and try to avoid slugging each other with the baggage.
Being agnostic sucks, I know. I am absolutely agnostic on most religious issues (neither accepting nor rejecting them in principle), and that usually means that I'm accused by turns of being atheist or theist, according to the preconceptions of the person I'm talking to. You gotta shake it off like a dog in the rain. If you're feeling stressed you should take a break, sure. But from what I've seen you're generally reasonable and insightful; you just need to 'grrr' a little less. But then don't we all…

I draw that distinction myself. Unfortunately, heated argument has a bad habit of driving out enlightening discussion... The problem is, discussion with people who have already made up their minds is rarely useful. Quoting a Tanith Lee's character in Brightly Burning Tiger, "There's no joy in conversions, and debate is normally pointless". While there is some value in providing answers to straighten out misunderstandings of the agnostic and/or scientific positions. it becomes tiring. Much as I hate to cede the field to the most emphatic, I'm not sure engaging with them is worth my time.

Religion is something that people love to argue about  I see it quite the contrary: Religion (and to a lesser extent language) form the structure of our subconscious. They come as close as we can get to discussion to our existential sense of who we and so  it matters deeply. Now it also happens that there are habitual argumentative folks.  These two facts tend to collide

You say:

Glanced at the SEP for the first time today, and noticed that most of it is focused on questions of the existence and character of deity or deities.

'God' and 'reality' are certainly central preoccupations of Western philosophy. But, I've been reading it for years, and never read anything theological and only "Philosophy of Religion". I suspect your perspective is skewed, and for some reason, the appearance of God (which to be fair was a central preoccupation of European philosophy during the Dark and Medieval ages and well past the Renaissance) in the SEP is as much a historical as well as a technical topic. It's hard to imagine Descartes or Kant without reference to God given how thoroughly immersed philosophy was in Christianity.
You say:

Having stepped in because a clarification/example of genuine agnosticism seemed to be needed, I am starting to feel that perhaps I have reached the end of my usefulness here and should step out again.

I always encourage everyone to participate to their fullest extent. You don't have to be useful. As an absurdist, I condone your being useless, ultimately because even the most knowledgeable contributors here are useless in their own way. It's an ironic aspect of philosophy that it is a humbling, overwhelming experience no matter how much "expertise" and "sophistication" one acquires in the topic. If one holds one's self up to the Western canon, the breath, depth, and width of it being overpowering, one must deal with one's own inconsequential existence, even most professional philosophers. We throw around names like Spinoza, Hume, and Kant, but we should never aspire to their fame. If nothing else PhilSE is a place to acquire patience, humility, and the odd lesson on critical thinking, history, and philosophical theory.

Preliminary Note

Kristian Berry's answer reminds me there is a literal reading of this question.
But then a literal reading is about SEP, making it off-topic for SE, still more an SE-meta.
So as a preliminary note:
This answer interprets the SEP reference as saying that if SEP represents the objective state of philosophy and SEP is found to be overfilled with God can someone explain to me why I should be interested — in SEP/Phil-SE/philosophy?

Short Version of Long Answer
This is a Western-Christian site, populated by Western-Christians with a definite anglophone/US slant.
People dont notice this and seem generally to get more upset when this is pointed out than to see the glaring facts.
So with the aid of chatGPT I've put together this case in a broad based way.
Religion, Christianity and Western Philosophy
A sane view on the matter would run as:

Christianity is one religion among many
Philosophy may overlap and intersect religion/Christianity but is distinct

Unfortunately it does not pan out that-a-way for many reasons as I elaborate below.
To start with, the central figures of the western philosophical canon were for the most part religious persons.  This may not be true in the last ½ century but a century is a thin translucent veneer on 2½ millennia of history.
Consider:

Kant was a pietist
Descartes escaped solipsism via God
Berkeley was a priest (and slave owner)
Hegel's summum bonum was God
Spinoza was of course God mad
Wittgenstein claimed that as a frontline soldier during WW-I, he owed his life to carrying about Tolstoy's summary of the Gospels in his pocket
And Schopenhauer was irreligious because he preferred Buddhism and the Upanishads to Christianity!

This does not even touch on Aquinas, Pascal, Kierkegaard and such. Note Occam in particular who is invariably (mis)used against his own more fideist-than-Aquinas purposes.
And all of Socrates, Plato, Aristotle, Marcus Aurelius, Epicurus, Epictetus, Seneca, were each religious in a pre-Christian world.
The only notable significant exceptions I can think of are Hume, Marx, Nietzsche and Freud.
Of these Freud is not quite a philosopher and Nietzsche is an atheist only by a literalist reading of his words.
Marx's 'materialistic idealism' killed many more than the Nazis — 'nuf said.
Only Hume is a real mainstream canonical western atheist — exception proves the rule?
Personal Note

I find Christians who — welcome or unwelcome — unctuously push their Christianity onto all an sundry irritating, but only mildly so.
I find atheists who thump their atheism (very much a religion though faux) more annoying simply because they are more cocksure that they are in the right — “Christianity is a belief, science is the Truth.”
But most of all I find the folks here who imagine they are not talking of religion at all but talking CI (Kant), democracy, liberalism, ethics, rights and so much else seemingly secular but all inexorably follows from the Protestant breakaway of Luther, Henry-VIII etc from Catholicism the most galling. See Brad Gregory for the long but straignt line from Catholicism to the Protestant breakup to modernity

I set out to write this answer because like you I think there is way more religion on this site than there should be on a healthy philosophy discussion forum.
Worse, it is one-sided, misnamed religion because its called 'religion' but scratch it just a little and it's almost always a denatured ‘decaffeinated’ Christianity.
2. The Historical dominance of Christianity in the West

Christianity has shaped Western thought, ethics, law, and education
for centuries. Even secular or post-religious societies often operate
within frameworks originally developed in Christian contexts.
Western philosophy of religion has historically dealt with issues like
the nature of God, arguments for God's existence (e.g., the
ontological, cosmological, and teleological arguments), and the
problem of evil, all of which are largely framed by Christian
theological concerns.
For example, the concept of a personal, omnipotent, omniscient, and
omnibenevolent deity is not universal. Many Eastern and indigenous
traditions, such as Buddhism, Jainism, and some strands of Hinduism,
conceive of divinity differently or eschew the concept entirely. Yet
these ideas are often sidelined in Western theological debates.

3. Christianity: A Fundamentally Teleological Universe

Central Belief: Christianity posits that the universe has a definitive purpose and direction, established by a personal and transcendent God. Creation is part of God's plan, and the ultimate purpose of life is union with God through salvation and grace.
Linear History: Time is seen as linear, with a beginning (Creation), pivotal events (e.g., the Incarnation), and an end (eschatology). The universe is heading toward a specific culmination in God’s Kingdom.
Teleology: Human existence and the cosmos are inherently purposeful, directed toward fulfilling God's will.

For comparison The Eastern Traditions:
Hinduism

Cyclic View of Time: Hindu cosmology views the universe as cyclic, undergoing endless cycles of creation (Srishti), preservation (Sthiti), and destruction (Samhara) by cosmic principles like Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva.
Dharma and Liberation (Moksha): The purpose of life is not tied to a single divine plan but to realizing one's true self (Atman) and its unity with the ultimate reality (Brahman). This realization transcends worldly existence, aiming for liberation from the cycle of rebirth (Samsara).
No Fixed Telos: The cosmos exists as a stage for individual souls to work out their karma and realize higher consciousness. It is not directed toward a final, universal end.

Buddhism

Impermanence (Anicca): The universe is seen as transient and without inherent purpose. Everything arises and passes away due to dependent origination (Pratītyasamutpāda).
No Creator God: Unlike Christianity, there is no divine being orchestrating the universe. Instead, the focus is on ending suffering (Dukkha) through enlightenment (Nirvana).
Personal Path: The ultimate goal is individual liberation from Samsara, not a teleological destiny for the cosmos.

Jainism

Eternal Universe: The universe is beginningless and eternal, governed by natural laws without a creator deity.
Karma-Driven: The moral law of karma drives the cycle of rebirth, and liberation (Moksha) is achieved through ascetic practices and self-discipline.
No Cosmic Purpose: Jain cosmology focuses on personal liberation rather than a teleological framework for the universe.

Sikhism

Creator and Sustainer: Sikhism posits a monotheistic God (Waheguru) who creates and sustains the universe. While there is a sense of purpose in aligning with divine will (Hukam), it does not emphasize a singular linear telos like Christianity.
Union with God: The goal of life is spiritual union with God through selfless service, meditation, and devotion, rather than the cosmos heading toward a final resolution.

Taoism

Natural Order (Tao):

Taoism centers on the Tao, the underlying, ineffable force that governs the universe. The Tao is not a creator in a theistic sense but a principle of harmony and balance that everything follows naturally.
There is no overarching teleological plan; instead, the universe unfolds spontaneously and cyclically, adhering to the Tao’s rhythms.


Wu Wei (Effortless Action):

The ideal life aligns with the Tao through wu wei, or effortless action, which involves living in harmony with nature and the flow of the universe without forcing outcomes.


Cosmic Perspective:

Taoism does not emphasize a personal or universal purpose. Instead, it focuses on being present, accepting the way of the Tao, and finding contentment in simplicity and balance.


Cyclic Time:

Similar to Hindu and Buddhist traditions, Taoism views time and existence as cyclical rather than linear, lacking a teleological culmination.



Zen

Here and Now:

Zen emphasizes direct experience and the immediacy of the present moment, de-emphasizing intellectual speculation about the universe’s purpose.
Like other Buddhist schools, Zen adheres to the principles of impermanence (anicca) and dependent origination (pratītyasamutpāda), rejecting teleological views.


No Creator or Design:

Zen does not posit a creator or a cosmic designer. It is more concerned with awakening to the nature of reality as it is, beyond dualistic thinking.


Satori (Enlightenment):

The goal in Zen is the realization of one's true nature through practices such as meditation (zazen), koan study, and mindfulness. This realization is non-linear and non-conceptual, emphasizing direct insight over theological frameworks.


Absence of Teleology:

Zen shares the Buddhist perspective that the universe does not have a predetermined purpose. Instead, liberation comes from transcending attachments and dualities, embracing the void (śūnyatā).



Key Contrasts



Aspect
Christianity
Hindu/Buddhist/Jain/Sikh
Taoism
Zen




Time
Linear and purposeful
Cyclical (Hinduism, Buddhism, Jainism) or balanced (Sikhism).
Cyclical, natural unfolding
Non-linear; present moment is emphasized.


Purpose of Creation
Directed toward God’s plan
Liberation from cycles of rebirth; no fixed cosmic end.
Harmonizing with the Tao
Awakening to reality as it is.


Role of a Creator
Personal, creator, and sustainer
Varies: personal (Sikhism), impersonal (Hinduism),  or absent (Buddhism, Jainism).
Absent; the Tao is not a deity
Absent; focuses on enlightenment.


Human Purpose
Salvation through divine grace
Self-realization, enlightenment,  or Moksha through effort or devotion.
Aligning with the Tao; simple living
Awakening to true nature (Satori).


Universe’s End
Eschatological culmination
Eternal cycles or liberation beyond materiality.
No definitive end; perpetual balance
Irrelevant; transcendence of dualities.



Compare with “secular” western philosophy/science. Are these coincidences to arising Christian milieu?

Hegel : History has a purpose
Marx : Killing millions for that purpose is kosher
Le Maitre (a Catholic priest) : Universe starts with Big Bang and ends with heat death

4. Atheists as "Christian Atheists"

Many prominent atheists, such as Richard Dawkins or Christopher
Hitchens, critique a conception of God that is essentially Christian.
Their arguments often presuppose:

A monotheistic, interventionist God who created the universe and is
involved in human affairs.
Scriptures that claim divine authority, such as the Bible or the
Qur'an.


This has led to the observation that many atheists are "Christian
atheists" in the sense that their rejection of religion is primarily a
rejection of Christianity rather than religion in its global
diversity. They often do not engage with, for instance, the atheistic
elements of Jainism or the apophatic theology of Hindu Advaita
Vedanta.

5. Indifference to Religion as Indifference to Chritianity

Secular or "indifferent" attitudes toward religion often stem from disillusionment with Christianity's cultural and political dominance rather than with religion as a whole.
This is evident in countries where Christianity was historically state-backed. For instance, in much of Western Europe, widespread secularization has left populations indifferent to religion, but this indifference is primarily toward Christian institutions and doctrines.

6. The Need for Broader Frameworks in Philosophy of Religion

The dominance of Christianity-centric frameworks limits the scope of
philosophical inquiry. For example:

Eastern philosophies like Buddhism or Taoism often focus on
practical paths to enlightenment or harmony, rather than theological
speculation.
Indigenous traditions may center on animistic or cyclical
worldviews, which challenge linear, salvation-oriented narratives
common in Christianity.


Scholars like John Hick and Raimon Panikkar have worked to expand
philosophy of religion to include comparative theology and pluralistic
approaches, but these remain underrepresented in mainstream discourse.

7. Religion = Theism = Atheism is a rejection of Theism

Framing: The equation of religion with theism, particularly
monotheism, leads to the assumption that rejecting religion means
rejecting a single, creator deity. This erases traditions that are
nontheistic (e.g., Buddhism, certain strands of Confucianism) or
polytheistic.
Implications:

Atheism as a product of theism: In rejecting theism, atheism often
remains entangled with the concepts it critiques, particularly the
idea of a personal, interventionist God.
Traditions like Jainism or Advaita Vedanta already propose
frameworks where "God" is irrelevant or purely symbolic. Western
atheism rarely addresses these non-theistic systems.


Broader View: Expanding the understanding of religion to include
nontheistic and non-Abrahamic paradigms allows atheism to evolve
beyond merely countering the Abrahamic deity.

8. Religion = Christianity = Protestantism = WASP Anglophone Protestantism

Framing: Much of Western philosophy of religion focuses on
Christianity, and within that, Protestantism — particularly in its
Anglo-American, WASP (White Anglo-Saxon Protestant) form. This often
marginalizes Catholic, Orthodox, and other Christian traditions, let
alone non-Christian ones.
Key Examples:

Scriptural focus: Protestant emphasis on sola scriptura (scripture
alone) leads to debates about literal versus metaphorical readings
of texts. Many other traditions prioritize rituals, oral traditions,
or mystical experiences over scripture.
Individualism: Protestantism's focus on personal salvation shapes
assumptions about religion as a primarily individualistic pursuit.
By contrast, Hinduism and Confucianism often frame spirituality in
collective or societal terms.


Implications:

This narrow lens reduces the diversity of religious experiences and
practices to a Protestant-like template. For example, concepts like
karma, dharma, or Zen are often shoehorned into Western
philosophical categories.
It also excludes religions without centralized scriptures or
hierarchical clergy, such as indigenous traditions or animistic
beliefs.



9. Religions as Personality Cults Around Divine Figures

Framing: Abrahamic religions often emphasize prophets or divine
figures (Jesus, Moses, Muhammad). This molds an assumption that
religion revolves around charismatic founders or central figures.
Contrast:

In Hinduism, while Krishna, Shiva, and others are venerated, the
focus often extends to impersonal truths (Brahman) or cosmic
principles (Rta).
Buddhism reveres the Buddha but also emphasizes practices and
philosophies over personal worship.
Taoism lacks a single divine figure, focusing instead on the Tao as
an impersonal force.


Implications:

This framework leads to a dismissal of traditions where no single
figure dominates (e.g., Shinto, Jainism).
It also reinforces a misleading view of religions as essentially
leader-driven, ignoring the role of decentralized practices,
community traditions, or evolving interpretations.



10. Theology = Philosophy of Religion

Framing: Theological discourse, particularly in the West, is often
synonymous with philosophy of religion, centering on questions like
the nature of God or proofs for God's existence. This approach
marginalizes non-theistic and non-Abrahamic traditions.
Problems:

This equates the study of religion with justifying or debating God's
existence — a distinctly Western concern.
Philosophies like Zen Buddhism, which avoid metaphysical
speculation, are sidelined in favor of Abrahamic-style debates.


Contrast:

Indian darshanas (philosophical schools) like Sankhya or Mimamsa
explore metaphysics and epistemology without invoking a deity.
Taoist and Confucian thought often treat cosmology and ethics as
inherently interwoven, without requiring theological justification.


Implications:

This limits the scope of philosophical inquiry into religion,
reducing it to theological concerns while ignoring ethical,
aesthetic, or practical dimensions of spirituality.



11. Religious Exclusivity Reflects Universal Truth Claims

Assumption: The exclusivist claims of certain religions (e.g.,
Christianity's "no one comes to the Father except through me") are
generalized to represent all religions.
Critique:

Many traditions embrace pluralism or relativism:

Hinduism: The Rigveda famously states, "Truth is one; sages call
it by various names."
Buddhism: Encourages finding truth through personal experience
rather than dogmatic adherence.
Indigenous religions: Often coexist with other faiths, seeing no
conflict in acknowledging multiple spiritual realities.


This assumption projects a competitive, zero-sum view of religion,
distorting traditions that emphasize coexistence or syncretism.



12. Religious Belief is Primarily Doctrinal or “Truth-claim” based

Assumption: Religion is often framed as a system of beliefs, with
doctrinal correctness being central. This is a distinctly Abrahamic
trait, particularly Protestant, where faith and adherence to creeds
are emphasized.
Critique:

Many non-Abrahamic traditions prioritize practice over belief. For
example:

Buddhism: The Four Noble Truths and Eightfold Path focus on
ethical living and meditation rather than doctrinal assent.
Hinduism: Dharma (duty) and karma (action) are central, with
belief systems varying widely among adherents.
Shinto: Emphasis is placed on rituals and honoring kami
(spirits), not on systematic theology.


This doctrinal framing marginalizes experiential or ritualistic
aspects of religion, which are primary in many traditions.



13. Religion is Primarily Moral Instruction

Assumption: Religion is seen as a system for teaching morality, with
divine commands or scriptures providing ethical guidelines. This
assumption often reflects Abrahamic religions where moral codes (e.g.,
the Ten Commandments) play a central role.
Critique:

In many Eastern traditions, morality is embedded in broader
cosmological or practical frameworks:

Taoism: Morality arises naturally from aligning oneself with the
Tao; it's less about commandments and more about harmony.
Confucianism: Focuses on relationships and societal roles rather
than divine mandates.
Zen Buddhism: Emphasizes mindfulness and compassion as emergent
properties of spiritual practice, not rigid moral rules.


This assumption reduces religion to a utilitarian tool for social
control, ignoring its metaphysical, aesthetic, and existential
dimensions.



14. Religion is Static and Immutable

Assumption: Religions are often treated as unchanging systems of
belief and practice, rooted in ancient texts or traditions, resistant
to adaptation.

Critique:

Religions evolve in response to cultural, political, and
technological changes:

Christianity: Has splintered into thousands of denominations,
adapting to diverse cultural contexts and social movements (e.g.,
liberation theology).
Buddhism: Spread from India to East Asia and adapted
significantly, leading to Zen, Pure Land, and Vajrayana schools.
Hinduism: Continues to evolve, with figures like Swami
Vivekananda reshaping its role in modern global contexts.




Treating religion as static ignores its dynamic nature and ability
to address contemporary issues.


15. Neglecting Sapir-Whorf Leads to a Slant of Viewpoint

Assumption: Discussions of religion and philosophy often ignore the
influence of language on thought, as proposed by the Sapir-Whorf
Hypothesis. The assumption is that religious or philosophical
concepts can be universally translated without distortion.
Critique:

Language shapes thought processes and worldviews. Key religious
concepts often have no exact equivalents across linguistic
boundaries, leading to misinterpretation. For instance:

Sanskrit terms like Dharma and Brahman lose much of their
layered meanings when translated into "law" or "God."
The Chinese term Dao (from Taoism) is often mistranslated as
"the way," stripping it of its metaphysical connotations.


Neglecting Sapir-Whorf perpetuates a dominant linguistic framework
(often English or Latin-rooted concepts) that molds discussions of
religion into a Eurocentric pattern.


Implications:

Comparative religion often ends up judging non-Western traditions by
Abrahamic standards because their core ideas are reframed through
Western linguistic and conceptual lenses.
Language's influence shapes everything from theological debates
(e.g., the existence of a "personal God") to ethical structures
(e.g., the individualistic versus collectivist framing of morality).



In essence neglecting Sapir-Whorf in studying religions produces an etic-but-not-emic reading of religion

You say you dont believe in God yet you believe in grammar
Nietzsche

More here
16. The exception becomes the rule
1. Anchoring

Beware of the man who's god is in the sky
George Bernard Shaw

Almost all extant world religions are geographically situated and anchored.
Eg.



Religion
Holy Land




Judaism
Jerusalem


Islam
Mecca, Medina, Karbala


Hinduism
Benaras (Kashi), Ayodhya etc


Sikhism
Amritsar


Buddhism
Lumbini, Gaya



Not to mention more nativist/tribal/“primitive” religions
Christianity: Is it really Bethlehem? Or more like Vatican?
chatGPT gives Vatican as 10-50 times more pilgrim visitors than Bethlehem depending on how/what you ask?
Now compare the Ṕlatonic actual significance of Vatican to Christianity as comepared to all the others.  All the others are central to the respective religions; Vatican is incidental.
This makes Christianity an unrooted, 'ever-foreigner' religion.
I believe this follows from the expulsion of the Jews from Jerusaelem in 80 AD which made Christianity an almost exclusively gentile religion
Since however Christianity sets the framing, the rooted aspect is treated as more primitive and the unrooted (called universal and other grand sounding names) as more advanced and civilized
2. Monotheism presumptions
Like secularism, monotheism is also a fantastic presumption.
Islam, Christianity and Judaism self-describe as monotheism or even as the only (possible) monotheisms.
As Dcleve described here, while Sikhism does not blow its trumpet on this front, it is arguably more authentically monotheistic than all these.
3. Pretensions to Secularism
UK, US and most of western Europe has fantastic pretensions to secularism. And yet have
violations of Secularism galore:
United Kingdom

Act of Settlement 1701:

Prohibits Catholics or anyone married to a Catholic from ascending to the throne, ensuring Protestant supremacy. This explicitly intertwines religion and the state, favoring Anglican Christianity over other beliefs.


Church of England's Role in Public Education:

Many Church of England schools are publicly funded and incorporate religious worship and teachings, which blurs the line between religion and secular governance.


Daily Religious Worship in Schools:

State schools in England are legally required to hold a daily act of collective worship, predominantly Christian in nature, though parents can opt-out their children.


Blasphemy Laws (Historical, Until 2008):

The UK's blasphemy laws protected only Christian beliefs, a clear bias toward one religion before their repeal.


Public Holidays Based on Christian Calendar:

Holidays like Christmas and Easter are national holidays, while similar recognition isn’t given to other religious or secular observances.



—
United States

Presidential Oath of Office

Traditionally taken on a Bible, and often includes the phrase "So help me God," reflecting a religious bias despite the Constitution’s secular intent.


National Prayer Breakfast

An annual government-endorsed event that blurs the line between religion and state, as it often involves political leaders advocating faith-based initiatives.


Religious Symbols on Public Land

Christian crosses and monuments on government property often remain, despite legal challenges arguing they violate the First Amendment.


Faith-Based Initiatives Office

Established under President George W. Bush, this office directs federal funds to religious organizations, raising questions about the separation of church and state.


State-Led Religious Exemptions

Several U.S. states allow businesses or individuals to refuse services (e.g., to LGBTQ+ individuals) based on religious beliefs, which critics argue prioritizes religion over secular law.



Western Europe

French Funding for Religious Schools:

Despite France’s principle of laïcité (secularism), the government partially funds private religious schools, particularly Catholic institutions.


German Church Tax (Kirchensteuer):

A tax collected by the state on behalf of recognized churches, making the government an agent for religious funding.


Spanish Subsidies for the Catholic Church:

Spain funds Catholic schools and pays clergy salaries, while also providing substantial tax exemptions to the Church under its Concordat with the Vatican.


Constitutional Recognition of Christianity (Norway):

The Norwegian Constitution declares the Evangelical Lutheran Church the state church and mandates its support.


Religious Broadcasting Rights (UK and Others):

Many countries allocate public broadcasting time specifically for Christian religious programming, often excluding other faiths or secular views.




This answer looks to me like it started out as a useful reply, but at some point turned into more of a personal rant.  Yes this site has a vocal anti-religion activist element.  And yes, the way this "anti-religion" perspective manifests as almost completely unaware of any religion other than fundamentalist Christianity is startling.  The philosophical perspective is to question the walls of the boxes one thinks within, and realizing that religion =/= fundamentalist Christianity should be obvious to everyone who posts here.  But this clearly is not understood by many regular posters.

However, I don't think this reply will break through those mental blinders.  It is too long, too angry, and too personanlized.

@Dcleve I respect your judgement. I can knock off the sections you find rant-y.  Or you can do it. I can make it community wiki to indicate it's a  collective pastiche of points. In any case it's hardly complete. So which sections come across as ranty should override (any presence to) completeness

It's an interesting essay, and I will have to read it more carefully when I have time to do so. But it isn't really an answer to the question, or if there is an answer it is buried in all of the other interesting stuff. May I suggest moving this to your own website, or a blogging site, and pointing to it from here? That will probably increase your focused readership, and likely your overall readership. And that will make it easier to print or file for later consideration. Stack Exchange is good for many things, but extended essays and deep analysis are rarely among them.

"brutal honesty" is one of those phrases that suggest you might want to check the enlightenment vs. heatedness ratio when tempted to use it, since it is more a statement of author frustration than anything else. I don't have objections to it, if you feel it's merited, but be aware that people encountering it may take offense and stop reading. Use judiciously, and preferably not before your final summary paragraph. (One of many tips summarized a bit rudely as "Real Writers rewrite to avoid the problem".)

Tnx @keshlam for the "rudeness". It's appropriate. I've changed the lead and removed the reference

@KristianBerry removed, See above comment
